# Cannot connect second monitor to laptop through a docking station

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, displayport, docking-station

I have a problem connecting my second monitor to my laptop through a docking station. It used to work but suddenly it stopped.

One day I mirrored my laptop to my TV and after instance I could not connect to my second monitor with my docking station. The docking station and the monitor are connected through displayport, and the docking station and my laptop are connected through a USB-C cable.
The issue is not with the docking station but with the laptop. I tried it with a different laptop and it worked, but the with specifik laptop that I used for mirroring on my TV screen it doesn't work anymore.
I tried to reinstall drivers för my USB-C port but it didn't work, I also tried to restore my system to a time period before I mirrored and it still did not work.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: undo what you did to mirror your laptop to your TV - you haven't mentioned what OS this is in, but I'm guessing from the lack of information that it's a flavour of Windows

Comment: What exactly happens when the laptop is plugged into the monitor? I'm assuming you're running Windows 10/11, if you right-click on your desktop and open 'Display Settings', what do you see? Also, have you checked which port the monitor is set to? Often you'll have to manually set the correct port on the monitor (besides DisplayPort, it might also have an HDMI port, DVI, etc).

Comment: What do you mean undo what I did. Yes it is a Windows HP laptop. When I mirrored I just pressed Windows key + K and chose my TV to mirror.

Comment: Yes I am running on Windows 11, when I open display settings I press on detect new display under multiple displays and it says that it doesn't detect anything. Normally this used to work before automatically just by plugging in the USB-C cable and I could see 2 displays.

Comment: Also I don't have an HDMI cable to test it on, I have always worked on DP cable

Comment: well, since I had NFI what operating system you're running, I though "undo what you did" was sage advice

Comment: I want to mention also that I have tried this on 2 different laptops and it worked fine, the monitor was detected without any problems. The problem is with one specific laptop.

Comment: Indeed you did mention that you tested another laptop in the question - what happens if you windows + k now?

Comment: It shows to me the available displays, but my monitor is not wireless so it does not show on the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147737/discussion-between-maso-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: what if you, I don't know, go to settings->system->display and try detecting other displays from there?